# Python - open diaglogbox on remote machine using ip address

Tags: python, dialog

In my python program (using tkinter GUI), i'm trying to open a dialogbox on a remote Linux machine address, using the machine IP address.
I looked for it, searched in forums and spend a lot of time trying to figure out if it's even possible but couldn't find a solution.

So, my question is:
Having a remote address such as:
username@192.168.1.103:/media/
is it possible to use an API for example: filedialog.askdirectory(), to open a dialog box, in which i can browse folders and choose one.
thank you

Update: I tried paramiko but i didn't give me what I expected - which is a diaglog box to browse, using a simple Gui (more or less similar to filedialog.askdirectory() ) appearance.

Comment: there are plenty of tools to connect to a remote address and browse folders. use ssh for example.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki, you can also provide few examples of them, e.g. [paramiko](https://pypi.org/project/paramiko/) as a very well known lib

Comment: open your console, type ssh user@ip, put the password and you are now connected and can navigate through the folders via console. you can also use an ftp program like filezilla which has a GUI.